# t-test when observations are years

Tags: time-series, t-test

I would like to know whether I can use the t-test or the non-parametric equivalent test when I have years as observations. Suppose I want to compare the profitability levels of two companies and I have profitability data over 10 years for each of the company. I thought I could use the company as if it was a treatment (i.e. company A or Not-Company A), and the years as cases. However, I fear this may pose problems of dependency, since the observations over time are likely to not be independent as would be, say, patients drawn randomly from a population.

I would very much appreciate any help, and would be happy to provide additional explanation if needed.

Answer (score 4):

Many years late, but:

This is not a good idea. Profitability of companies is likely to be autocorrelated. This means that observations are not independent, which is a basic assumption of t-tests. The autocorrelation structure can be accounted for in other analytical approaches.